# Sorting on a translable json column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I am using spatie translation  package in laravel. I have collection which i want to sort by name but the name column has a json collection due to which its not getting sorted.
I have tried

```
$shoptype->categories->sortBy('name.en');
```

and my result

````
{
"id": 8,
"type_id": 1,
"name": "{\"en\":\"Other Meats\",\"es\":\"Otras Carnes\"}",
"image_path": "http://market.test/uploads/category/Cpaf7nCVZxshoptype.png",
"created_at": "2021-04-02T12:13:14.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-08-14T06:17:35.000000Z",
"deleted_at": null
},
{
"id": 9,
"type_id": 1,
"name": "{\"en\":\"Turkey\",\"es\":\"Pavo\"}",
"image_path": "http://market.test/uploads/category/8U2qP2mrzashoptype.png",
"created_at": "2021-04-02T12:13:14.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-05-26T05:48:01.000000Z",
"deleted_at": null
},
{
"id": 10,
"type_id": 1,
"name": "{\"en\":\"Chicken\",\"es\":\"Pollo\"}",
"image_path": "http://market.test/uploads/category/SnP7mwnTeBshoptype.png",
"created_at": "2021-04-02T12:13:14.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-05-26T05:48:14.000000Z",
"deleted_at": null
},
{
"id": 11,
"type_id": 1,
"name": "{\"en\":\"Beef\",\"es\":\"Carne De Vaca\"}",
"image_path": "http://market.test/uploads/category/b7IKzAGUHDshoptype.png",
"created_at": "2021-04-02T12:13:14.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-05-26T05:48:50.000000Z",
"deleted_at": null
}```
````

Comment: I booted up my project that uses that package, and this doesn't work, working on a solution will be back :)

Comment: Thankyou very much, I am also looking and trying for the solution. Hope for the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SortBy` with callback.

use `collect` method to convert `categories` as `collection` if not

```
$categories = collect($shoptype->categories)->sortBy(function($category, $key){
       return (json_decode( $category->name))->en;
});
```

if `$shoptype->categories` is already a collection

```
$categories = $shoptype->categories->sortBy(function($category, $key){
       return (json_decode( $category->name))->en;
});
```

if `categories` is Json then use `json_decode($shoptype->categories);` and use `sortBy` with `collect` method

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby